# How to use sql queries as output in a Rshiny web page

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, dbi, sparklyr

So, I am trying to output a query to an Rshiny app but keep getting errors in the output. Here is my output:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

    library(shiny)
    library(DBI)

 for Spark 2.1.X
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME_VERSION="2.1.0")


#Connecting to Spark
sc <- spark_connect(master ="yarn-client")

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("nrows", "Enter the number of rows to display:", 5),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderTable({

    iris_preview <- dbGetQuery(sc,"select * from sndbx_dx.ncct_mapping limit 3")
    iris_preview

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Im simply trying to get iris_preview to show in the shiny app when i run it. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I want to output the tables from my Hive database since im connecting to spark.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example based on the iris dataset and sqlite to get you started:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(datasets)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)
dbListTables(con)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("nrows", "Enter the number of rows to display:", 5),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "queryButton",
    label = "Query",
    icon = icon("refresh")
  ),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  iris_preview <- reactiveVal(data.frame())

  observeEvent(input$queryButton, {
    queryString <- sprintf("select * from iris limit %s", input$nrows)
    iris_preview(dbGetQuery(con, queryString))
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    iris_preview()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

On the long run please read [this](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely).

Comment: Could I open a chat with you real quick? i have a few questions. Please and thank you

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask.

Comment: How do you show multiple query strings? So if i wanted to show another table, would I just copy and paste the observeEvent section with a different select clause?

Comment: Let me know when you're online and I will set up a chat.

Comment: To display another table you'll need a second [tableOutput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/tableOutput.html)